# VBA Type Mismatch When Checking for Cell Value and Cell Format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to shade cells based on if they have borders and if the cell value is blank.  I've developed the code below, but I keep getting a Type Mismatch error due to the code that is bolded.  Is it possible to check for both cell format and values in this manner?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim R1 As Long
Dim G1 As Long
Dim B1 As Long
Dim R2 As Long
Dim G2 As Long
Dim B2 As Long
Dim R3 As Long
Dim G3 As Long
Dim B3 As Long
Dim R4 As Long
Dim G4 As Long
Dim B4 As Long

R1 = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("B27")
G1 = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("B28")
B1 = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("B29")
R2 = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("B31")
G2 = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("B32")
B2 = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("B33")
R3 = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("B36")
G3 = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("B37")
B3 = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("B38")
R4 = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("B41")
G4 = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("B42")
B4 = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("B43")

Dim My_Range As Range

Set My_Range = Worksheets("Final Output").Range("C8:G19,I8:N19,P8:U19,W8:AB19,AD8:AI19,AK8:AP19,AR8:AW19,AY8:BD19,BF8:BK19")

For Each cell In My_Range


    If cell.DisplayFormat.Font.Bold = True And cell.DisplayFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone Or cell.DisplayFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium And cell.DisplayFormat.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(R1, G1, B1)
        cell.Font.Color = RGB(R3, G3, B3)
    **ElseIf cell.Value = "" And cell.DisplayFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous And cell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight <> xlMedium Then**
        cell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(R2, G2, B2)
        cell.Font.Color = RGB(R4, G4, B4)
    **ElseIf cell.DisplayFormat.Font.Bold = True And cell.DisplayFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous Or cell.DisplayFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous And cell.DisplayFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin And cell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight <> xlMedium And cell.Value = "" Then**
        cell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(R2, G2, B2)
        cell.Font.C olor = RGB(R4, G4, B4)
    ElseIf cell.DisplayFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous And cell.DisplayFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin And cell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous And cell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight <> xlMedium Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(R2, G2, B2)
        cell.Font.Color = RGB(R4, G4, B4)



End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `DisplayFormat` from `cell.DisplayFormat.Borders`.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Unfortunately, that still results in the same error from the same line.  I think it has something to do with how I have cells in the range defined (or how I failed to define them).  Additionally, I believe I need to keep the 'DisplayFormat' as I am also looking for cells that have been conditionally formatted with borders.

Comment: The problem might be with `RGB(R3, G3, B3)` in the line before the indicated line. Also, it wouldn't hurt to use `Option Explicit`, which is useful in debugging.